# WordPress category foreach pagination?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Last week I wanted to replace the posts from the first category with all its subcategories. So far it works well except for the pagination. What I mean by that:

When I click Next, the page reloads and the URL changes to /page/2 but it shows the same range of subcategories as before. No matter how many times I click next after that it reloads the page but is the same content and URL. If I click Previous, the list changes to the last 5 subcategories, meaning the 13th page as shown in the photo, but it shows Page: of 13 (no number). In other words, nothing works properly in the current pagination code.

I'm sure there's a better way, similar to the post pagination with links for each page instead of just Previous and Next, but nothing worked what I tried so far. Any help to make the pagination work is appreciated. Thanks a lot! This is how it looks:

[image]

```
<?php
    $descendant= array('child_of'=>1);
    $cats = get_categories($descendant);

    $limit = 5;

    $total = count($cats);
    $pages = ceil($total / $limit);
    $result = ceil($total / $limit);

    $current = isset($_GET['paged']) ? $_GET['paged'] : 1;
    $next = $current < $pages ? $current + 1 : null;
    $previous = $current > 1 ? $current - 1 : null;

    $offset = ($current - 1) * $limit;
    $cats = array_slice($cats, $offset, $limit);
?>

<div class="container">
    <?php foreach ($cats as $cat) { ?>
        <div>

        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) ); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a>

        
        <?php $query = $cat->count; ?>
        <?php if ($query == 1) $query .= " Post"; else $query .=" Posts"; echo '('.$query.')'; //Posts Count ?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <br>
    <?php echo "<p>(Page: ". $current . " of " . $result .")</p>"; ?>
    <br>


    <? if($previous): ?>
        <a href="<?php home_url(); ?>?paged=<?= $previous ?>">Previous</a>
    <? endif ?>
    <? if($next) : ?>
        <a href="<?php home_url(); ?>?paged=<?= $next ?>">Next</a>
    <? endif ?>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, please _properly_ explain what "not working" actually means.

Comment: The links Previous and Next do not work when you click them.

Comment: "do not work" isn't a helpful problem description, and merely a repetition of what you already said. Do you get _errors_? Do they not cause a new _request_ at all? Do they reload the page, but still show the _same_ range of categories as before?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I added more details, please take a look.

Comment: The links you created have `?paged=...` at the end, so I am not sure how you would end up on `/page/2` then? Is there a redirect happening?

Comment: Maybe simply try a different parameter name for the page number, `paged` and `page` might collide with the default WP paging mechanism somehow.

Comment: Brilliant! You're right. I renamed ?paged into ?page and now it works well. There's still one little issue: I would like to remove the Previous link on the first page. Post it as an answer if you know how please, and I will accept it as the correct one.

Comment: Not sure why the previous link would show on the first page, `$previous` should be null, making the link not show to begin with. Can you add a `var_dump($previous);`, to verify what it contains?

Comment: It says NULL. The same thing happens to the last page, the Next link should not be visible but it is.

Comment: Ah, the `if` and `endif` statements are simply getting completely ignored, because you used just `<?` - use `<?php` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The links you created had `?paged=...` at the end, but you ended up on `/page/2`- so apparently this "overlapped" with the default WP pagination mechanism. Using a different parameter name, should be able to fix that.

```
<? if($previous): ?>
    <a href="<?php home_url(); ?>?paged=<?= $previous ?>">Previous</a>
<? endif ?>
```

The link will get generated even if `$previous` is null - because `<? if($previous): ?>` and `<? endif ?>` have simply been ignored by the PHP parser, since `short_open_tags` if set to off. Start each of those PHP blocks with `<?php` instead of `<?`, then this should work, too.

Comment: True! I replaced the <? and the Previous link does not show up on the first page anymore. Again, thanks a lot!